# Symetrical positions in matrix

Tags: c++, c, math, matrix, symmetric

Given an (i,j) element in a matrix what is the symmetrical correspondent in the matrix. I am trying to create a function that generates a symmetrical matrix in c. Thanks a lot.

Also would it be wise to create a matrix "by hand" using the rand() functionality or read from file, if I am dealing with large matrixes?

Comment: The first question is super easy, but I don't understand your second question. `rand` will give you a random matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given an (i,j) element in a matrix what is the symmetrical correspondent in the matrix

In a symmetric matrix `A`, `A(i, j) == A(j, i)`.

> Also would it be wise to create a matrix "by hand" using the rand() functionality or read from file, if I am dealing with large matrixes?

This is impossible to answer without some context. However, if you want a random matrix and don't need to preserve it across runs, there's no reason to save it in a file.